# Get built-in or connected webcam vendor name

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, webcam

I am trying to get the vendor name of the web-cam that may be built-in for macbook or iMac Or external for the MacMini.

I am getting information using:

```
system_profiler SPCameraDataType
```

But using this I am not able to get the vendor name only.

I also get around QTKit.framework using which I can get the the video device info:

```
NSArray *devices = [QTCaptureDevice inputDevicesWithMediaType:QTMediaTypeVideo]
NSArray *devices = [QTCaptureDevice inputDevicesWithMediaType:QTMediaTypeMuxed]

for (QTCaptureDevice *device in devices) 
{
    NSLog(@"Device : %@", [device description]);
}
```

But here also there is no vendor name.

Please suggest me the way to get vendor name for the webcam device.

Comment: That code will not compile.

Comment: @Droppy I have not put exact code, it is for example.